# Como referenciar propriedades de um userForm para uma sub, no excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu criei um formulário em vba (excel) e neste formulário contém um checkbox, eu gostaria de acionar determinado comando se o checkbox for marcado, contudo o código para ser acionado está em uma módulo de `sub` separado do `userForm`.

Gostaria de saber como posso referenciar o checkbox. Segue abaixo o código a ser acionado:

```
    If (ccbDeleteForms = True) Then
        plRelatorio.Activate
        Rows("10418:40000").Select
        Selection.Delete
    End If
```

Comment: Problema resolvido, bastava usar o (nome do formulário).(propriedade a ser referenciada) Como por exemplo, highwaySelection.ccbDeleteForms.locked = false

Answer (score -1):

Você solucionou, porém eu tenho uma solução mais genérica:

Se você passar o CheckBox como parâmetro, fará com que não necessite referenciar o userform no teu método e assim você pode passar qualquer objeto.

```
Sub ChecarCkb(obj As Object)
    If TypeName(obj) = "CheckBox" Then
        If obj Then MsgBox "Objeto está selecionado"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    'Aqui você passa o objeto
    Call ChecarCkb(CheckBox1)
End Sub
```